# Can you help completing this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to come up with a sentence but I am having a hard time at that :(
I want to say the following "look what just arrive in my home/house! I live in Brazil, isn't it crazy/cool to have your work going all the way to the other side of the world?".

Just some context in case it helps, I'm writing this to a novel writer I'm a fan, which happens to be very active on twitter lol(don't worry about characters tho), by now I could come up with something , but I am having trouble with the "isn't it crazy" part. Please help me, also if the part I've got so far sounds dorky, help make it better.

What I've come up so far:
私の家に到着したものを見て。私はブラジルに住んでいます。

ありがとうございます。

EDIT: I have gone a bit further: 私の家に到着しましたものを見て。私はブラジル住んでいます。君の文学作品が遠くに達しましたの物はすごいね。

I feel like everything but the last part is right, in the last part i was trying to say "The thing/fact of your literal work reaching so far is amazing, isn't it?" Am I close, guys?

Comment: "Isn't it" sentence enders: ね, な, じゃない, でしょう, だろう. All-purpose word for awesome/amazing/cool: すごい

Comment: Thank you, I am at work right now but as soon as I leave I'll try to finish the sentence with that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Look what just arrive in my home/house! I live in Brazil, isn't it crazy/cool to have your work going all the way to the other side of the world? / The thing/fact of your literal work reaching so far is amazing, isn't it?
>   私の家に到着しましたものを見て。私はブラジル住んでいます。君の文学作品が遠くに達しましたの物はすごいね。

I think it'd be a bit more natural and politer if you said...

> たった今私の家に到着したものを見てください！私はブラジルに住んでいますが、XX先生*の作品が｛こんなに遠くまで / はるばるブラジルまで / こんな遠い地球の[裏側]{うらがわ}まで｝やってくるなんて、すばらしいですよね！

or

> 今ちょうど私の家に[着]{つ}いたものを見てください！私はブラジルに住んでいるんですが、XX先生*の作品が｛こんなに遠くまで / はるばるブラジルまで / こんな遠い地球の[裏側]{うらがわ}まで｝[運]{はこ}ばれてくるなんて、すごいですよね！

(*It would be politer to use "family name + 先生" to refer to the writer. I don't recommend using あなた, much less 君.)

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Yeah, i'm still really bad at the politeness thing, actually that's what i'm studying right now (masu stem).  As you can see i'm a beginner and i am lerning on my own so I am still not good at making complex sentences. But once again, thank you!

Comment: There's a part where you refer to the writer as a "sensei", why's that?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Yes, we use 先生(sensei) to address novelists, manga writers, artists, lawyers, politicians etc., as well as teachers and doctors. You could refer to this article: [Sensei on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensei)

Comment: I figured out the complete meaning of the sentence, now i have only 2 questions left `XX月先生の作品がこんなに遠くまで やってくるなんて`
is `こんな` refering to `XX月先生の作品`? 

and is `なんて` modifying `遠くまで やってくる`?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira こんな modifies 遠く, so こんな遠くまで is like "this far" or "so far (as this)". ～なんて... (which is like などとは or とは) is like "It is... that~~" in English. You use it to show your surprise, amazement, etc., e.g. 「こんなに安い**なんて**驚きです！」(It is surprising that this is so cheap!) 「フランス語が話せる**なんて**すごいですね！」(It's great that you can speak French!)

Comment: ＠chocolate I get it! Thanks a lot for the examples, it really helped to clarify things, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the given sentence - 私の家に到着したものを見て。私はブラジルに住んでいます。ありがとうございます, I guesss the writer is saying "I've read your work you sent over to me who's living far from you in Brazil. Thank you very much." though I'm afraid if this interpretaion makes sense in English or not.

But in the same token, the quote doesn't make sense even in Japanese at all. It should be rewritten to make it undertandable.